# React-navigation, ScreenStack only accepts children of type Screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

After upgrading react navigation to version 6 as per these instructions, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x/

I get the error, ScreenStack only accepts children of type Screen, any ideas how I can fix it?

App.js:

```
export default () => {

  const linking = {
    prefixes: ['', ''],
    config: {
      screens: {
        Register: 'register',
        MyVehicle: 'MyVehicle',
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
                <AppRootStack />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

AppRootStack:

```
const AppRootStack = () => {
  const { appState, appContext } = useContext(AppContext);
  const { isLoading } = appState;
  const { registerCallbackCompleted } = appContext;

  if (isLoading === true) {
    return <SplashScreen />;
  }
  return (
    <RootStackNavigator
      {...appState}
      registerCallbackCompleted={registerCallbackCompleted}
    />
  );
};
```

RootStackNavigator:

```
 const RootStackNavigator = ({
   
    }) => {
         
      return (
        <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName={initialRouteName} mode="modal">
    
          <RootStack.Screen
            name={AppRoutes.Register.Name}
            component={RegisterScreen}
            options={{
              title: AppRoutes.Register.Label,
              headerShown: false,
              animationEnabled: false,
            }}
          />
        </RootStack.Navigator>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that `react-native-screens` was `v2.x` rather than `v3.x`.

Comment: so u did u upgraded ?